# how to call functions recursively in async.waterfall?

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, recursion

```
async.waterfall([
    function(callback) {
        callback(null, 'one', 'two');
    },
    function(arg1, arg2, callback) {
      // arg1 now equals 'one' and arg2 now equals 'two'
        callback(null, 'three');
    },
    function(arg1, callback) {
        // arg1 now equals 'three'
        callback(null, 'done');
    }
], function (err, result) {
    // result now equals 'done'
});
```

Beginner here, just wondering. I need to call functions 2 and 3 recursively depending on the output of function 3. Would a async.doWhilst work if I put functions 2 and 3 in one async.series function?

Comment: If you define the functions outside of the `async.waterfall` block, you can call them with the third function.

Comment: I was thinking of doing that but I want to pretty much run function 2 and 3 recursively depending on the output of function 3. I was thinking of using asnc.whilst but it only allows for 1 function. Do you think I should make 1 function and put an async.series in there for my two functions to iterate over? I edited my main question to reflect this.

Comment: @SarodhUggalla: Yes, that'll do. Although you may consider scrapping `async.js` completely and writing it by hand right away.

Comment: as in using promises instead of async?

Comment: wondering what the right way is in this case.